# Syzygies of $Gr_{2}(\mathbb{C}^4)$

Tags: geometry, algebraic-geometry, modules

I'm going to start the study the problem of syzygies. I read on web that it is possible to compute syzygies of an algebraic variety for example $Gr_2(\mathbb{C}^4)$, but I don't understand how can I find syzygies of a variety because in my definition I can only calculate syzygies of a $R$-module $M$. Can you explain how can I find syzygies of $Gr_2(\mathbb{C}^4)$ and give me some reference?

Comment: The syzygies depend on the embedding, right? So probably you want to take the universal line bundle $L$ defining the Plücker embedding and compute a resolution of $\bigoplus_m H^0(mL)$ over $\operatorname{Sym} H^0(L)$.

Comment: If you by "syzygies" mean a resolution of the ideal of the Plücker embedding, then your example $Gr(2,4)$ is trivial, since the ideal is principal.

Comment: So is it possible to computer syzygies of $Gr_k(\mathbb{C}^n)$ in general? (In the Pluker embedding)

Comment: Yes, the ideal has quadratic generators known as the "Plücker relations" (a Google search will give them to you). In fact, there is a nice degeneration of the ideal to a monomial ideal which have the same resolution (see http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0512283), and syzygies of monomial ideals can be computed on a computer quite fast.